# C# int? parameter- Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, null, int

I am trying to call a stored procedure which has an INT parameter (BusinessID) and allows NULL. From my C# code, I can't figure out if data is null, how to identify and pass. I have listed three techniques I have tried numbered #1,#2,#3 and the errors I get. Please guide
Here is my sample code:

```
private static DataRow ValidateRecord (string ProjectNum, int? BusinessID)
{
    DataRow returnRow = null;
    using (SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "[dbo].[mySQLProc]", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 90;

                command.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNum", SqlDbType.VarChar, 17).Value = ProjectNum;

                // #1 – error: "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."
                //if (!BusinessID.HasValue)
                //{
                //    BusinessID = (int)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null; 
                //}

                //#2 - "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."
                if (BusinessID == null)
                {
                    BusinessID = (int)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null;
                }
                //#3  - error on compile time – Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
                // there is no implicit converstion between ‘System.DBNull’ and ‘int?’
                //  BusinessID = BusinessID == null ? DBNull.Value : BusinessID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@BusinessID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BusinessID;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                returnRow = CreateDataRow(ProjectNum, BusinessID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return returnRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `BusinessID = (int)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null;` - try `(int?)` also whether `BusinessID` is null or not you're still passing it to the stored procedure I'm not sure why you're checking for null if the SP can handle it.  Not sure what version of .net you're using but maybe change `command.Parameters.Add("@BusinessID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BusinessID;` to `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessID", BusinessID);` - Hope this helps

Comment: It might be to do with you including the '@' symbol in the name - whenever I create SqlParameters, I drop the '@' e.g. `new SqlParameter("BusinessID", BusinessID)`

Comment: same error with (int?)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null;

Comment: if I do command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessID", BusinessID); and pass null, then the stored procedure doesn't even recognize it as if @BusinessID is missing

Comment: Worked!!! command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessID", (Object)BusinessID ?? DBNull.Value);

Comment: command.Parameters.Add("@BusinessID",  (int?)BusinessID);